# Trigger not launched from interface

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ado.net

I have a table with an after update trigger in SQL 2005. If I update directly with SQL QUERY the trigger runs ok.

This table is connected using a dataset and tableadapter to a DXDBGrid (Dev. Express).

If the user updates the grid, the underlying data is updated, but the trigger is not launched.

I've a PK on table, auto-generated UPDATE command in the table adapter, etc. Everything works fine except the trigger not launching...

Why, oh why!?

Thanks in advance.

Franklin.

EDIT: The trigger code:

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgUpdateZonasAsignadas]
   ON  [dbo].[ZonasAsignadas]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

```
IF NOT(UPDATE(ActualizadoPDA))
BEGIN
   UPDATE ZonasAsignadas SET ActualizadoPDA=0
      WHERE IdUsuarioZona IN (SELECT Inserted.IdUsuarioZona FROM Inserted)   
END
```

END

Comment: How do you determine the trigger wasn't run?

Comment: Can you show us the trigger code?

Comment: To Silky: the column "ActualizadoPDA" is not update when from the interface.

Comment: I'd claim that the trigger IS running, but you're just not getting the data you expected. I'm not totally sure what that 'if not(update(xx))' is doing though.

Answer (score 1):

This code will only fire if the "ActualizadoPDA" column is changed. If your grid ships with the same value of "ActualizadoPDA" it had before, the trigger isn't going to fire, **even if it's included in the update statement.**

It looks like what you want is something like "IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Inserted WHERE ActualizadoPDA = 0)" instead. Or, if you just want to mirror the value, eschew the IF statement altogether and just do a straight update. If everything's indexed properly, the time spent on it should be negligible.